# Insert Into SP in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wrote a query to insert data to a oracle table in Oracle-SQL Developer.

[image]

when Executing SP following error comes. What is the reason?

[image]

Comment: That is not a package. It is a procedure.  You don't show your pl/sql block, so who knows...  Also you should normally not embed a commit in a procedure.  Let the caller determine transaction lifetime.

Comment: No, you are missing semicolons.  This did not even compile.

Comment: Please don't post code as screenshots. Post code as formatted **text**

Answer (score 1):

every statement in sql & plsql should ends with semicolon ; which not exists in insert statement, commit and end commands in your code.